# Angular- jsPDF warnings, uncexpected tocken and jsPDF.fromHTML is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf

I want to print html code whit jsPDF in Angular but i cant. i need help, look.

ts.config.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": [],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

npm jspdf module

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgSk3.png)

angular.json scripts

```
 "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
              "node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.es.min.js"
            ]
```

if in the class i import like this `import jsPDF from 'jspdf';` or like this `import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";` i get this warning and this error.

warning:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js 195:141-151
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.umd.min.js 195:240-254
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

error:

```
scripts.js:18390 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

if i import jspdf like this `import * as jsPDF from "jspdf";` i get this error:

error:

```
Type 'typeof import("jspdf")' has no construct signatures.
    const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
```

this is my class:

```
//PDF
// import { jsPDF } from "jspdf";
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';
// import * as jsPDF from "jspdf";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cash-register',
  templateUrl: './cash-register.component.html'
})
export class CashRegisterComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild("ticket") ticket: ElementRef;

public printPDF(): void {
    var pdf = this.ticket.nativeElement.innerHTML;
    const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');

    const margins = {
      top: 80,
      bottom: 60,
      left: 40,
      width: 522
    };

    doc.html(pdf, {
      callback: function(doc) {
        doc.save("Test1.pdf");
      }
    })

    // or
    
    doc.fromHTML(pdf, margins.left, margins.top, {}, function () {

      doc.save("Test2.pdf");
    }, margins);
  }
}
```

and if i not import jspdf in angular.json i get this error when i tried to download:

```
core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: doc.fromHTML is not a function
```

Comment: When you load something as a script like that, you wouldn't import it but rather access it as a global. Since it appears to be a module why are you loading it as a script?

Comment: fromHTML was working then I updated my angular from 9 to 10 now I am getting doc.fromHTML is not a function.

Comment: Yeah im working in angular 10 @Nakres

Comment: @AluanHaddad, because in the all tutorials the people import that as a script, but i will tried your suggestion..

Comment: Any working solution yet? Seems with every version of jsPDF something breaks. Too bad!

Comment: check the [release note](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/releases): Removed APIs that were previously marked as deprecated. Namely: `addHTML`, `fromHTML`, `html2pdf`, `addSvg`, `addButton`, `addTextField`, `addChoiceField, cellInitialize, setFontStyle, setFontType, clip_fixed.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a good solution but this is how I made it work. It looks like jspdf 2.0.0 is throwing "doc.fromHTML is not a function." in angular 10 (I am not sure if it works in the previous angular versions.)

I removed jsdpf 2.0.0 using

```
npm uninstall jspdf
```

Then I installed the previous version which is:

```
npm install jspdf@1.5.3
```

WorkingExample:

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';


var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
var imgData =
  'data:image/png;base64,addAnImageData';
var specialElementHandlers = {
  '#idDiv': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};
doc.addImage(imgData, 'png', 0, 250, 615, 200);
let source = document.getElementById("idDiv");
doc.fromHTML(source, 0, 0, {
  'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
doc.save('card.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `doc.fromHTML()` issue happened on Angular 7.x too. If downgrade to jsPDF 1.5.3, it can work properly.